# Since on c the size of double and char* are the same and the size of float and int are the same, is there a way how to distinguish between them?

Tags: c

I am trying to code a program that accepts any type as "elements" and stores them in a set but the set itself must be of the same type meaning if my 1st element is an integer, all the other elements must be integers. I've managed to get so far using `sizeof` but later discovered that the `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` are of the same size and would not distinguish the difference between an integer and a float, similarly for `double` and `char *`.

#### Below is the code I tried to identify `int` from `float`

```
if (set->element_size == sizeof(int))
{
    char checker[STRINGL];
    snprintf(checker, sizeof(checker), "%.9f", *((float *)set->elements));

    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(checker) + 1; j++)
    {
        if (!((checker[j] >= '0') && (checker[j] <= '9')))
        {
            if (checker[j] == '.')
            {
                printf("Element is of type float. Cannot add element to the set.\n\n");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Below is the code I tried to identify `double` from `char *`

```
if (set->element_size == sizeof(char *) && strchr(set->elements, '\0') != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp((const char *)element, (const char *)set->elements + i * set->element_size) == 0) // Compares string/characters with previous.
    {
        printf("Element is already in set.\n\n");
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Element is of type double. Cannot add element to the set.\n\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: "Since on c the size of double and char* are the same and the size of float and int are the same" is a false assumption. C does not specify these sizes, they are implementation (hardware) dependent.

Comment: My bad then. Since my code is considering both int and float to be of the same size, I assumed it's as it is. Any way to go around this?

Comment: Don't make any assumptions at all. Instead if you want to use generic data, use arrays of bytes and let the user of your functions decide the size of the data and what type it it. Pass the data as `void *` pointers, and copy to or from the byte arrays.

Comment: Alternatively use [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic).

Comment: @Tootoo1910, Using `size` of objects are insufficient to deduce its type.  Many different object types have the same size.  Alternatives depend on coding goals, of which OP needs to describe more.

Comment: The goal is to enter elements along with the size and add the element to the set. If the user decides to enter another element with different type, The program won't accept the element. I considered using enums but I am not sure if they are the right tool to use..

Comment: Have you looked at _Generic?  You still need to write a type-specific function (wrapper at least).

Answer (score 0):

No.  Once the compiler translates the code, all the information about the data type can only be deducted from the instructions accesing it.  You cannot distinguish a value represening a floating point number from an integer representing the same thing or a sequence of bytes representing e.g. a DNA sequence.